# Create Test Class in IntelliJ

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm working within the traditional Maven Java project structure inside IntelliJ, e.g.

```
main/java/com/x/y
test/java/com/x/y
```

When I create a class called Foo in *main/java/com/x/y* using IntelliJ I would like to automatically have a file called FooTest.java created in *test/java/com/x/y*.

In Eclipse there is a button on the toolbar that will do much of the work involved in creating a skeleton test class, does anyone know of something similar in IntelliJ?

Thanks,

Comment: The directories structures for tests and tested classes must fit. Here is how to do it easily: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36057708/715269

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Use the menu selection *Navigate* -> *Test*, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on Mac). This will go to the existing test class, or offer to generate it for you through a little wizard.

Comment: In my project for some reason, even though the class and the test class are located in the same package, when I did Ctrl+Shift+T it says "No Test Class Found". Also, when I right click on the test file, it only gives me the option to compile test, but not run test. Any idea?

Comment: Off hand I'd answer as Andreas did at your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161058/intellij-mvn-project-test-classes-not-functioning). Somehow it doesn't recognize that your classes are tests.

Comment: Still works nicely with 12.1.4 in Windows. Check in Settings that the Keymap binds Mainmenu/Navigate/Test to Ctrl+Shift+T

Comment: Didn't work for me - _until_ I re-enabled the JUnit plugin which had somehow been disabled.

Comment: Works in 13.0.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Does not work w my IntelliJ IDEA 14 Win: I get error "No test subjects found" if I ctrl-shift-t on class or no response at all if using menu or keys on project tree. JUnit is enabled. I was able to get the Create Test popup if I clicked into class body and then used menu or ctrl-shift-t.

Comment: It should be noted that *Navigate > Test* is disabled when the class is selected in the Project window.  It must be selected in an editor tab.

Comment: in the `Create Test` Dialog, how can I check all the methods at once?

Comment: In IntelliJ 2020.1.2, right-click on the class name in the editor. Then Generate -> Test.

Answer (score 45):

Alternatively you could also position the cursor onto the class name and press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> (*Show intention actions and quick fixes*). It will suggest to *Create Test*.

At least works in IDEA version 12.

Comment: For me, this is the most logical option. I've overridden CTRL+SHIFT+T to be "restore previous tab" so the ALT+ENTER combo on the class name works well.

Comment: Works on Intellij Idea 2018.2.

Answer (score 12):

**IntelliJ 13 ** (its paid for)  We found you have to have the cursor in the actual class before <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> worked.

Which seems a bit restrictive if its the only way to generate a test class. 
Although in retrospect it would force developers to create a test class when they write a functional class.

Answer (score 9):

Use the menu selection **Navigate > Test**

[image: gif]

Shortcuts:

## Windows

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

## macOS

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

I can see some people have asked, so on OSX you can still go to navigate->test or use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Remember you have to be focused in the class for this to work

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click on project then select new->directory. Create a new
   directory and name it "test".
2. Right click on "test" folder then select Mark Directory As->Test Sources Root
3. Click on Navigate->Test->Create New Test
   Select Testing library(JUnit4 or any)
   Specify Class Name
   Select Member

That's it. We can modify the directory structure as per our need. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I was getting "Generate tests in same root as source?" trying the above, this was just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can always try the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to find the action/command you need.
Here you can try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and input «test» to find the command.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Test annotation on one of the test methods or annotate your test class with @RunWith(JMockit.class) if using jmock. Intellij should identify that as test class & enable navigation. Also make sure junit plugin is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

With the cursor on the class name declaration I do ALT + Return and my Intellij 14.1.4 offers me a popup with the option to 'Create Test'.