# IntelliJ mvn project test classes not functioning

Tags: intellij-idea

In my maven project for some reason, even though the class and the test class are located in the same package, when I did Ctrl+Shift+T it says "No Test Class Found".

More importantly, when I right click on the test file, it only gives me the option to compile test, but not run test.

I'm able to run the tests successfully if I just do mvn clean install in command line.

Any idea?

Comment: Hard to say, please provide a sample project to reproduce.

Answer (score 6):

You need to mark the test files/directories as "Test Sources" in Project Settings -> Modules?